# How to rotate left section of element around y-axis 25 degrees

Tags: css

I am looking to create a style rule that rotates the aside elements within the left section 25° around the y-axis, and to Create another style rule that rotates the aside elements within the right section –25° around the y-axis.

css:

```
section-left.aside {
transform: rotateY(25deg);
}

section-right.aside {
transform: rotateY(-25deg);
}
```

html:

```
    <section id="right">
  <aside>
     <h1>Merchandise</h1>
     <p>Special discount pricing on all Chupacabra15 clothing, posters and
        souvenirs available now. Gift cards and volume pricing are also
        available.</p>
     <p>Shop our <a href="#">online store</a> to get the best deals.</p>
  </aside>
  <aside>
     <h1>Online Chat</h1>
     <p>Snow Storm Pilot will be hosting an online chat to discuss
        their upcoming concert tour. Enter a <a href="#">drawing</a> to win a VIP pass 
        for their show at Chupacabra15!</p>
  </aside>
  <aside>
     <h1>Sponsors</h1>
     <p>Visit our <a href="#">Sponsors Page</a> to get great online deals
        for Chupacabra15 promotional items and merchandise.</p>
     <p>Want to become a sponsor of this great event? <a href="#">Contact
        us</a> to learn how!</p>
  </aside>
```

Can someone please advise what i'm missing?
Thanks so much

Comment: Hello @Yechiel are you sure your definitions are correct? Normally asides are html elements and sections too but in this case you seem to have section classes. Can you add your html structure so that we can check if the rules are correct?

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure you apply CSS rules correctly.
There is no `section-left` html element. I suppose you got messed
Please try:

```
.left .aside {
transform: rotateY(25deg);
}

.right .aside {
transform: rotateY(-25deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment i think your rules are incorrect.

I made a codepen example you can check [here](https://codepen.io/mi_ov/pen/gOOVrzE).

```html
<div style="width: 1200px; margin: 0 auto;">
  <section class="left">
    <aside>123</aside>
    <aside>123</aside>
  </section>
  <section class="middle">
    <article></article>
  </section>
  <section class="right">
    <aside>456</aside>
    <aside>456</aside>
  </section>
</div>
```

```css
.left, .middle, .right {
  float: left;
  min-height: 500px;
  background: #DDD;
}

.left {
  width: 25%;
}

.middle {
  width: 50%;
  background: #EEE;
}

.right {
  width: 25%;
}

.left aside {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(25deg);
}

.right aside {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(-25deg);
}
```

Basically you have to review your code structure and update the definitions accordingly.

Be careful not to mix html elements with classes.

If you need more info on CSS selectors you can check this article on [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Just click "Run code snippet"

```js
var deg = 360;
const $div1 = $('#myDiv1');
const $div2 = $('#myDiv2');
const $btn2D = $('#btn-2d');
const $btn3D = $('#btn-3d');
const $solution2D = $('#solution-2d');
const $solution3D = $('#solution-3d');

$(function() {
  $btn2D.on('click', function() { $('.solution').hide(); $solution2D.show() });
  $btn3D.on('click', function() { $('.solution').hide(); $solution3D.show() });
  
  rotate();
});

function applyRotation($target, mode) {
  let prefix = (mode == '3d') ? 'perspective(500px) ' : '';
  $target.css('transform', prefix + 'rotateY(' + deg + 'deg)')
}

function rotate() {
  applyRotation($div1, '2d');
  applyRotation($div2, '3d');
  $(document).delay(2000).queue(function() { deg+=360; rotate(); $(this).dequeue() });
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'arial';
}

.spinner {
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #FA0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  transition-duration: 2s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  margin: 10px 20px;
  float: left;
}

.spinner span {
  display: block;
  transform: rotateZ(90deg); /* or just rotate(90deg) */
}

.solutions {
  clear: both;
}

.solution {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px dashed gray;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 310px;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.content, .left, .right {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: #EEE;
}

.content {
  text-align: center;
}

aside {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #EEE;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#solution-2d aside.left {
  float: left;
  transform: rotateY(30deg);
}
#solution-2d aside.right {
  float: left;
  transform: rotateY(-30deg);
}

#solution-3d aside.left {
  float: left;
  transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(30deg);
}
#solution-3d aside.right {
  float: left;
  transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(-30deg);
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv1" class="spinner"><span>:D</span></div>
<div id="myDiv2" class="spinner"><span>:O</span></div>

<div class="solutions">
  Choose your desired style:
  <button id="btn-2d">2D</button>
  <button id="btn-3d">3D</button>
  <div id="solution-2d" class="solution">
    <aside class="left">transform: rotateY(10deg);</aside>
    <div class="content">2D</div>
    <aside class="right">transform: rotateY(-10deg);</aside>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="solution-3d" class="solution">
    <aside class="left">transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(30deg);</aside>
    <div class="content">3D</div>
    <aside class="right">transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(-30deg);</aside>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```